# How to move advanced search into left of homepage and delete its own page

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I am making a custom theme based on the rwd theme in magento 1.9 and would like to know how i can move the advanced search into the left of my homepage and delete its own page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalogsearch"><title>Advanced Search</title></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalogsearch/advanced_form" name="catalogsearch_advanced_form" template="catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: Does this go into the local xml?

Answer (score 0):

1st you need to convert home page in 2columns-right or 2columns-left

After that added advanced search option on  home page by placing this code in **/app/design/frontend/default/hellowired/template/page/2columns-right.phtml**

`echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalogsearch/advanced_form')
->setTemplate('catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml')->toHtml() 
?>`

it's working for me. 
Happy Coding. :)

Comment: Where do you put it in the file? in col-left sidebar?